# Catching error in FQL data if a particular data is missing example current city

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have been trying to retrieve the following data using the following code in php:

```
$fql_query='SELECT%20name,%20birthday_date,%20sex,%20current_location.name,%20email%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid=me()';<br>
  // Run fql query<br>
  $fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
    . '/fql?q='.$fql_query
    . '&' . $access_token;<br>
  $fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql_query_url);<br>
  $fql_query_obj = json_decode($fql_query_result, true);<br>
```

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com//fql?q=SELECT%20name,%20birthday_date,%20sex,%20current_location.name,%20email%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid=me()&access_token=)
>   [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request
>   failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in  on line 223

I believe the following error is because the user has not provided current location in the profile. If I add the data the code works fine. How do I catch that error?

Comment: You can paste your $fql_query_url into your browser and get the error message. (for example not returning any data, or asking for data you don't have access to) Now, how to catch it in code, that's what I'm trying to do myself...

Answer (score 0):

"[function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in on line 223"

Would tell you that as the function is failing, it can be tested logically for a result e.g.

```
$fql_query='SELECT%20name,%20birthday_date,%20sex,%20current_location.name,%20email%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid=me()';

  // Check FQL query
  $fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
                   . '/fql?q='.$fql_query
                   . '&' . $access_token;<br>

  // First logically check the result, TRUE: Result is passed to $fql_query_result.
  //                                   FALSE: $flq_query_result = 0 or false.
  $fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql_query_url) ? file_get_contents($fql_query_url) : 0;

  // Only json_decode the result if it was valid.
  $fql_query_obj = (!$fql_query_result == 0) ? json_decode($fql_query_result, true) : "FQL was not a valid query";
```

Comment: Thanks. It was helpful. I did not yet test the result, but I got the point what you are trying to make. Thanks again.